# How do I figure out what maven artifacts to include in my POM after looking at the list of imports?

Tags: java, maven

I'm reading some sample code for a technology I'm learning about.  In one of the source files, there are several imports:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;
```

In this case, I know that I'm learning about Jersey and Jetty, but I'm quite lost when trying to figure out which articfacts to resolve all the dependencies such as above.  I'm running searches on http://mvnrepository.com/ but there are so many choices.  How do I know which dependencies are the right ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a class search on the Maven repository, for example: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22javax.ws.rs.Path%22

This will give you a list of artifacts, anyway it is up to you to choose which versions to use.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily this issue doesn't come up too often - mostly when writing a Maven project, you find artifacts by discovering the technology first (i.e. via Google searching), then find the Maven artifacts by following the advice on the project websites.

In your case, where you are trying to retrofit a suitable Maven dependency into existing code, there is no easy way. A variety of online tools can assist you in finding JARs that contain certain classes (for instance http://mavenhub.com/).  I would then typically scan through that list and look for the "obvious" contenders.

E.g. searching MavenHub for `ServletContextHandler`, the `jetty-servlet` artifact looks promising. At this point, I'd probably search http://mvnrepository.com and try the latest release.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.3.v20140225</version>
</dependency>
```

If your code compiles, you've probably got it right. Of course, if your tutorial gives any advice about version numbers, try to follow that when downloading the artifacts.

Comment: seems like a lot of trial and error.  Perhaps after I've done this a few more times I will have a better sense

Comment: @MedicineMan It's not that common to approach the problem from this direction, so hopefully you won't need to get too practised at it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no way to determine which dependencies are needed along with their correct versions. However there is a work around for what you are trying to achieve.

1. Remove imports that you think require maven dependency.
2. Errors will pop-up in front of you.
3. Now your IDE will suggest you to add maven dependencies. (I assume you have maven            configured IDE) Add those dependencies one by one.

Thus, you get to know which dependencies were necessary for project to run.